# system clock is not set correctly on startup

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

i have strange problem with the system clock in my Linux system, TinyCore, kernel 2.6.38 .
dmesg says the following:

```
rtc_cmos 00:04: setting system clock to 2012-08-08 19:20:00 UTC (since_epoch-value)
```

but actually, when i test `date`, it always starts as 1/1/2001 01:43:00, while hwclock shows the correct time.
now if i run `hwclock -s`, it's fixed until the next boot.
this system is like a "live CD" that's loaded to RAM and umount the storage device.
my guess is that the kernel indeed set the time from rtc0, but maybe a file overwriting resets the system clock. could it be (included /dev/something)?

Comment: I've answered with a solution, but exactly do you mean with: *"system is like a live CD"* ?

Comment: i mean there is no non-volatile storage in that system. so in every boot, the same filesystem is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

### Background

In Linux, the system time zone is determined by the symbolic link `/etc/localtime`.

This mentioned link points to a time zone data file that describes the local time zone. The time zone data files are located at either `/usr/lib/zoneinfo` or `/usr/share/zoneinfo` depending on what distribution of Linux you use.

### hwclock

hwclock is a tool for accessing the Hardware Clock. You can display the current time, set the Hardware Clock to a specified time, set the Hardware Clock to the System Time, and set the System Time from the Hardware Clock.

> The Hardware Clock: This is a clock that runs independently of any control program running in the CPU and even when the machine is powered off.

If you use `-s` it will set the System Time from the Hardware Clock. That why you get the problem fixed.

### Solution

You can execute a command in your terminal to set the symbolic link, it will persist even after reboot:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Portugal /etc/localtime
```

<sup>For me its Portugal, adapt the command to your time zone.</sup>

Comment: the distribution is TinyCore, and i don't have /usr/lib/zoneinfo nor /usr/share/zoneinfo nor /etc/localtime.
can it cause this problem that the time is not updated from boot, but updated correctly when i `hwclock -s` manually?